# Visual Basic: Exit a console application from a class which is NOT in the Main module

Tags: vb.net

I'm having some trouble in code that I'm writing where I want to exit the console application, should it have an error (caught in a try/catch).  The application, as mentioned, is a console application. This means that System.Windows.Forms.Application is NOT included as a reference and is unavailable for me to use.

So if I grab an error produced outside of the Main module, in a separate class, how do I exit the program from that class?

Please keep in mind I cannot use Application.Exit() so please do not offer that as a solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `Environment.Exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

[`Environment.Exit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx) will work, but I think the better practice will be to re-throw the exception and let the main module catch it again and quit the program, or if you're not doing anything else in the exception handler, let the exception bubble up to the main module in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same problem and what I had to do was make a function within a separate Module instead of making it a Sub Routine.

Then I returned "True" if it passed the test and "False" if it did not pass the test. Then I included the below code in the Main Module.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub GetScreenInfo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GetScreenInfo.Click

        Dim WeAreOnTheCorrectScreen As Boolean
        Dim ScreenText As String

        ScreenText = GetScreenText()

        WeAreOnTheCorrectScreen = CorrectScreenTextValidation(ScreenText)

        If WeAreOnTheCorrectScreen = False Then Exit Sub

    End Sub

End Class
```

Lastly, just a note. "GetScreenText()" and "CorrectScreenTextValidation()" are functions in separate modules.

I didn't include their sample code because I am just trying to convey the general idea to accomplish what you want to do.

Bottom line, the answer is to return a value from a function and then use a one line "If" statement to exit the sub, if needed.

```
If WeAreOnTheCorrectScreen = False Then Exit Sub
```